# How to get same field thats in multiple nested parts of object

Tags: json, mongodb, get, nested

I am trying to query a mongodb database to give a Boolean for whether a series of different beaches are present among all the JSON data.

Clip of JSON data:

```
"availability": {
        "monday": {
            "available": true,
            "day": "Monday",
            "startTime": ["0900", "1400"],
            "endTime": ["1230", "1700"],
            "beaches": ["Ocean Beach", "South Mission Beach", "Mission Beach", "Pacific Beach", "Tourmoline", "La Jolla Shores"]
        },
        "tuesday": {
            "available": true,
            "day": "Tuesday",
            "startTime": ["0900", "1400"],
            "endTime": ["1230", "1700"],
 I want this--->  "beaches": ["Ocean Beach", "South Mission Beach", "Mission Beach", "Pacific Beach", "Tourmoline", "La Jolla Shores"]
        },
        "wednesday": {
            "available": true,
            "day": "Wednesday",
            "startTime": ["0900", "1400"],
            "endTime": ["1230", "1700"],
            "beaches": ["Ocean Beach", "South Mission Beach", "Mission Beach", "Pacific Beach", "Tourmoline", "La Jolla Shores"]
        },
```

...continued

This is what I have so far,

`Instructor.collection.distinct('availability')`

Not sure how to access, "beaches" array while ignoring the different parents of these fields.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the data, there can be maximum of 7 possible sub-documents inside the 'availability' document i.e. a sub-document for a day. If its the case, you can fetch the distinct beaches using the following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
            "beaches":{
                $concatArrays:[
                    {
                        $ifNull: ["$availability.monday.beaches",[]]
                    },
                    {
                        $ifNull: ["$availability.tuesday.beaches",[]]
                    },
                    {
                        $ifNull: ["$availability.wednesday.beaches",[]]
                    },
                    {
                        $ifNull: ["$availability.thursday.beaches",[]]
                    },
                    {
                        $ifNull: ["$availability.friday.beaches",[]]
                    },
                    {
                        $ifNull: ["$availability.saturday.beaches",[]]
                    },
                    {
                        $ifNull: ["$availability.sunday.beaches",[]]
                    },

                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$beaches"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$beaches"
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"NO_GROUP",
            "beaches":{
                $push:"$_id"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Output:

```
{
    "beaches" : [
        "La Jolla Shores",
        "Tourmoline",
        "Ocean Beach",
        "Mission Beach",
        "South Mission Beach",
        "Pacific Beach"
    ]
}
```